# What is the syntactical structure of a += statement in python?

Tags: python, syntax, expression

I have discovered something in python today. But haven't found a clear explanation for it yet.

In python it seems that this works:

```
variable += a_single_statement
```

So, following statements are correct:

```
variable += another_variable
variable += (another_variable - something_else)
```

But doing the following is incorrect:

```
variable += a_variable - b_variable
```

Could someone explain why this is the case, preferably with a link to the documentation to the syntactical structure that explains what the operands of a `+=` operator are, what expressions are expected and what their structure is? Also, are my thoughts, outlined above, even correct?

The behavior seems to be different from other programming languages I'm used too, and that last 'statement' leads to a syntax error.

Edit: the code where it doesn't work. It might be a whitespace error instead :/

```
T = input()
counter = 0

# For each word, figure out edit length to palindrome
for _ in range(T):
    counter += 1
    word = raw_input()
    word_len = len(word) #stored for efficiency
    index = 0
    sum_edits = 0

    # Iterate half the word and always compare characters 
    # at equal distance d from the beginning and from 
    # the ending of the word
    while index < word_len/2.0:
        sum_edits += max(ord(word[index]), ord(word[word_len-index-1])) -
                min(ord(word[index]), ord(word[word_len - index - 1]))
        index += 1

    print sum_edits
```

It's code to detect how many edits it would take to make a word into a palindrome, if you could only change letters 'downwards' towards an 'a'.

Does this mean you can not arbitrarily break up a line in python code, if it's clear that the 'expression' has to continue anyway? Or can you only break up lines of code if they are surrounded with parentheses? 
Sorry, I'm very new to python.

Comment: `variable += a_variable - b_variable` is perfectly fine.

Comment: `variable += a_variable - b_variable` should work just fine. Can you show a minimal example that produces the error when you paste it into an interpreter session or run it as a `.py` file? Most likely, the error is something like a parenthesis on the previous line you forgot to close.

Comment: For a bit more detail: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Comment: Thanks. I think it might be a whitespace error instead. I'll post the code above. It's a rather small example anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `+=`. It's just that Python doesn't let you split a statement across multiple lines unless there's an open `(`, `{`, or `[`, or unless you perform a line continuation with `\`. It might look obvious that those two lines are supposed to be one statement, but then when you have statements like

```
a = loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing
  + ooooooooooooootheeeeeeeeeeeeer_thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing
```

is that one statement or two? If you allow

```
a = loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing +
    ooooooooooooootheeeeeeeeeeeeer_thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing
```

to be one statement, then either interpretation for having the `+` operator on the second line is confusing and bug-prone. Javascript tries to allow this kind of thing, and its semicolon insertion causes all kinds of problems.

It's usually recommended to use parentheses if you're not already inside brackets or braces.

Comment: Thanks! Old habits die hard I guess. Different language, different rules. :)